# Document.ready method is called after pageload method - Jquery 3.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am facing one strange issue. I am upgrading my project to latest jQuery version 3.3.2. I have created a sample page which contains only update panel and a javascript link.

Now problem is instead of calling document.ready method, when I refresh the page (run the application), pageLoad method is called first and then document.ready method gets called.

I have tried using older version of jQuery 2.2.4 and up to that it was working fine with update panel, but when I upgraded to latest version 3.x.x it creates an issue.

Below is sample code

default.aspx page

```
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>--%>
<script src="Scripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div> Page body
</div>
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm" ScriptMode="Debug" EnableCdn="false"
EnablePartialRendering="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
<CompositeScript>
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" />
</Scripts>
</CompositeScript>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upSnapshot" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
Update panel body
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
alert('document.ready');
});
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
alert('Pageload');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **ready** event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the **onload** event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

The onload event is a standard event in the DOM, while the ready event is specific to jQuery. The purpose of the ready event is that it should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded.

Where you have invoked the **pageload()** method ?
Can you share the HTML?

Comment: @DENENDRA DHINDA, Thanks for your time and sharing things. HTML is already there in my previous comment. pageload method of javascript is being invoked by scriptresource.ax file because i have used update panel on my page. I have not explicitly mentioned that method anywhere on my HTML